# Use Vim to "colourize" files or input streams

Tags: vim

This may be an odd question, but still. I use `cat` to display a file in bash (KDE Konsole),

```
cat foobar.rb
```

Now, I would like to use Vim to colourize that `foobar.rb` file according to what you would get when you start `foobar.rb` in Vim. Edit: But only for display purpose, on the terminal.

I am not sure this is possible, but I thought it would be neat if I could use Vim for that.

I really just want colourized keywords, and Vim has the perfect colour definitions.

So I thought combining this would be great.

Is this possible in Vim out of the box though?

Comment: Do you literally just want to dump the file to the console, or do you want the facilities of e.g. `less` (e.g. ability to page up and down)?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use a library such as [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), which is a general purpose syntax highlighter. You could write a wrapper called `ccat` or something that would apply syntax highlighting to an input file and write to stdout.

If you want to page up and down in a highlighted file, you can use `less` with the `-R` switch, which passes control characters through to the terminal directly, preserving colours. So:

```
ccat file.rb | less -R
```

But at that point, you're pretty much at the capabilities of `view`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you are only looking for a command that will give you a read-only view of the input file (like cat) but with coloured keywords, use `view`. `view` is an alternative way to start `vim` in read-only mode, so you have all syntax highlighting possibilities. From the vim man page:

```
   view      Start  in read-only mode.  You will be protected from writing
             the files.  Can also be done with the "-R" argument.

   gvim gview
             The GUI version.  Starts a new window.  Can also be done with
             the "-g" argument.

   evim eview
             The GUI version in easy mode.  Starts a new window.  Can also
             be done with the "-y" argument.

   rvim rview rgvim rgview
             Like the above, but with restrictions.  It will not be possi-
             ble  to  start  shell  commands, or suspend Vim.  Can also be
             done with the "-Z" argument.
```

I have always seen view on systems that have vim installed.

Comment: Oh I see! Never heard that one before.

Answer (score 2):

Closest is the `less` script that comes with vim:

```
cat myfile | vim -u /usr/share/vim/vim72/macros/less.vim -
```

Note the `-` argument to vim. You may need to change the `vim72` to your version (and the whole path if you have it installed elsewhere)

Now, this isn't exactly what you want, because its behaviour is `less`-like, in that you have to press keys to make it scroll down or complete. However, they are briefer than usual vim. For example, <kbd>space</kbd> to scroll down; and <kbd>q</kbd> to quit (not `:q`).

You want a `cat`-like version; me too. But there doesn't seem to be one.

**EDIT** uh, there's also a `vimpager` project, that includes `vimcat` - exactly what you want. But it doesn't come with vim, and I haven't tried it yet.

- vim.org: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1723
- github: https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager